# Run multiple gulp files in Laravel Elixir

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I am creating a particularly large system and so to help manage it I'm using caffeinated modules to split it up into logical, self-contained modules. I'd like to be able to keep all assets for each module inside the module's folder and then have a gulp file for each module that does what it needs to.

This is my example structure:

```
/
├── app/
|   └── Modules/
|       ├── Foo/Resources/assets
|       |   ├── images/
|       |   ├── js/
|       |   |   └── foo.js
|       |   ├── sass/
|       |   |   └── foo.scss
|       |   └── gulpfile.js
|       |
|       └── Bar/Resources/assets
|           ├── images/
|           ├── js/
|           |   └── bar.js
|           ├── sass/
|           |   └── bar.scss
|           └── gulpfile.js
|
└── gulpfile.js
```

So when I run `gulp` I would like it to execute the gulp file in the root directory and all the gulp files in the `Modules` folder. I've tried including the files dynamically but I need it to pick up all files in the folder without specifying the name of each module, so when I add a new module I create the gulp file and it will automatically be run.

I've spent hours searching and trying various things but so far the only thing I've managed to get sort of working is to manually specify each gulp file using `require('./app/Modules/Foo/Resources/assets/gulpfile.js');` but not managed to get it to load up for all modules without specifying them individually.

Is this even possible? If so how? If not are there any alternatives that will work and do what I need?